# Jquery Css unable to highlight input type button label text onclick radio button

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I want to know how can i able to mark input type radio button label text on click radio button . With help of some of the answers here  in SO its working on label click but i am unable to mark highlight when i clicked radio button.

```js
$('label').click(function() {
  $('label').removeClass('orangeBackground');
  $(this).addClass('orangeBackground');
});
```

```css
.orangeBackground {
  color: #CE5A0B;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade listing-id" id="closeListingModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog closelistingmodal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content closelistingmodal-content">
      <form class="closelisting-form form-horizontal" onsubmit="return false" role="form" data-listing-id="" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="listing_id">
        <input type="hidden" name="listing_weight">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="closelistingmodal-body modal-top-padding">
          <div class="col-sm-12 ">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 cell-no-padding">
              <input type="radio" name="reason-closing" value="1" id="rad1"><label for="rad1"> Rate Mismatch</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 cell-no-padding">
              <input type="radio" name="reason-closing" value="2" id="rad2"><label for="rad2"> Program Cancelled / Differed</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 cell-no-padding">
              <input type="radio" name="reason-closing" value="3" id="rad3"><label for="rad3"> Vehicle Unavailable</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 cell-no-padding">
              <input type="radio" name="reason-closing" value="4" id="rad4"><label for="rad4"> Listing Fulfilled By Party</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 cell-no-padding">
              <input type="radio" name="reason-closing" value="5" id="rad5"><label for="rad5"> Payment Terms Mismatch</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 cell-no-padding">
              <input type="radio" name="reason-closing" value="6" id="rad6"><label for="rad6"> Wrong Post</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 ">
              <label>Rate PMT:</label>
              <input class=" form-control row-margin input-pmtftl-amount" type="text" id="closelistinginput-value" name="listing_pmt" value="" placeholder="Rate In PMT (₹)" / min="0">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 no-of-trucks">
              <label>Weight (MT):</label>
              <input class="no-of-trucks form-control " type="text" name="listing_weight_mt" value="" id="noOfTrucks" min="1" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 ">
              <label>Rate FTL:</label>
              <input class=" form-control input-pmtftl-amount" type="text" id="closelistingftl-input" name="listing_ftl" value="" placeholder="Rate In FTL (₹)" / min="0">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
              <textarea type="text" class=" form-control row-margin" name="listing_notes" placeholder="Notes" /></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hidden-xs">
              <textarea type="text" class=" form-control row-margin" name="listing_notes" placeholder="Notes" /></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer ">
          <button class="v2-button  closing-submit-btn" name="closelisting-submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Iamge 1 ..
[image: First snippet when i clicked its respective label]

Image 2...
[image: When i clicked radio button previous label won't unmarked with new one]

Any help will be highly appreciate. 
Thanks

Comment: Converted to snippet and I don't see any issues.

Comment: @SergChernata check this snippet .  
https://jsfiddle.net/pw8Ld6cs/ 

If you hit any abel its get checked with highlighted colour but if you hit any radio button its respective label won't get changed.

Comment: When do labels change back to black?

Comment: @ErikPhilips when i checked a new button.

Comment: @TanmoySarkar a Radio button with the same name right?

Comment: @ErikPhilips yeah .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying the click to only the label and the input checkbox is outside it and won't trigger the click, so simply put it inside the label like this :

```js
$('label').click(function() {
  $('label').removeClass('orangeBackground');
  $(this).addClass('orangeBackground');
});
```

```css
.orangeBackground {
  color: #CE5A0B;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade listing-id" id="closeListingModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog closelistingmodal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content closelistingmodal-content">
      <form class="closelisting-form form-horizontal" onsubmit="return false" role="form" data-listing-id="" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="listing_id">
        <input type="hidden" name="listing_weight">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="closelistingmodal-body modal-top-padding">
          <div class="col-sm-12 ">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 cell-no-padding">
             <label for="rad1"> <input type="radio" name="reason-closing" value="1" id="rad1"> Rate Mismatch</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 cell-no-padding">
             <label for="rad2"> <input type="radio" name="reason-closing" value="2" id="rad2"> Program Cancelled / Differed</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 cell-no-padding">
              <label for="rad3"> <input type="radio" name="reason-closing" value="3" id="rad3">Vehicle Unavailable</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 cell-no-padding">
              <label for="rad4"><input type="radio" name="reason-closing" value="4" id="rad4"> Listing Fulfilled By Party</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 cell-no-padding">
              <label for="rad5"> <input type="radio" name="reason-closing" value="5" id="rad5">Payment Terms Mismatch</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 cell-no-padding">
              <label for="rad6"><input type="radio" name="reason-closing" value="6" id="rad6"> Wrong Post</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 ">
              <label>Rate PMT:</label>
              <input class=" form-control row-margin input-pmtftl-amount" type="text" id="closelistinginput-value" name="listing_pmt" value="" placeholder="Rate In PMT (₹)" / min="0">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 no-of-trucks">
              <label>Weight (MT):</label>
              <input class="no-of-trucks form-control " type="text" name="listing_weight_mt" value="" id="noOfTrucks" min="1" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 ">
              <label>Rate FTL:</label>
              <input class=" form-control input-pmtftl-amount" type="text" id="closelistingftl-input" name="listing_ftl" value="" placeholder="Rate In FTL (₹)" / min="0">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
              <textarea type="text" class=" form-control row-margin" name="listing_notes" placeholder="Notes" /></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hidden-xs">
              <textarea type="text" class=" form-control row-margin" name="listing_notes" placeholder="Notes" /></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer ">
          <button class="v2-button  closing-submit-btn" name="closelisting-submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution

```
input[type="radio"]:checked+label{
    color: #CE5A0B;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cxerg55f/

Answer (score -1):

This should do it, use a class (here I called it "radioBtns") for the inputs/labels that will capture the click.

```js
$(".radioBtns").click(function() {
  $('label').removeClass('orangeBackground');
  $(this).parent().children("label").addClass('orangeBackground');
});
```

```css
.orangeBackground {
    color: #CE5A0B;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="modal fade listing-id" id="closeListingModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog closelistingmodal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content closelistingmodal-content">
      <form class="closelisting-form form-horizontal" onsubmit="return false" role="form" data-listing-id="" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="listing_id">
        <input type="hidden" name="listing_weight">

        <div class="modal-header"> 
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="closelistingmodal-body modal-top-padding">
          <div class="col-sm-12 "> 
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 cell-no-padding">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 cell-no-padding">
              <input type="radio" name="reason-closing" value="1" id="rad1" class='radioBtns'><label for="rad1" class='radioBtns'> Rate Mismatch</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 cell-no-padding">
              <input type="radio" name="reason-closing" value="2" id="rad2" class='radioBtns'><label for="rad2" class='radioBtns'> Program Cancelled / Differed</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 cell-no-padding">
              <input type="radio" name="reason-closing" value="3" id="rad3" class='radioBtns'><label for="rad3" class='radioBtns'> Vehicle Unavailable</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 cell-no-padding" >
              <input type="radio" name="reason-closing" value="4" id="rad4" class='radioBtns'><label for="rad4" class='radioBtns'> Listing Fulfilled By Party</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 cell-no-padding">
              <input type="radio" name="reason-closing" value="5" id="rad5" class='radioBtns'><label for="rad5" class='radioBtns'> Payment Terms Mismatch</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 cell-no-padding">
              <input type="radio" name="reason-closing" value="6" id="rad6" class='radioBtns'><label for="rad6" class='radioBtns'> Wrong Post</label>
            </div> 
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-12">    
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 ">
              <label>Rate PMT:</label>
              <input class=" form-control row-margin input-pmtftl-amount" type="text" id="closelistinginput-value" name="listing_pmt" value="" placeholder="Rate In PMT (₹)"/ min="0">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 no-of-trucks">
              <label>Weight (MT):</label>
              <input class ="no-of-trucks form-control " type="text" name="listing_weight_mt" value="" id="noOfTrucks" min="1" />
            </div> 
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 ">
              <label>Rate FTL:</label>
              <input class=" form-control input-pmtftl-amount" type="text"  id="closelistingftl-input" name="listing_ftl" value="" placeholder="Rate In FTL (₹)"/ min="0">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-12"> 
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
              <textarea type="text" class=" form-control row-margin" 
                name="listing_notes" placeholder="Notes"/></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hidden-xs">
              <textarea type="text" class=" form-control row-margin" 
                name="listing_notes" placeholder="Notes"/></textarea>
            </div>  
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer ">
          <button class="v2-button  closing-submit-btn" name="closelisting-submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pay attention as you are applying this to a block element, so when i click on the whole row i trigger the click. Try click on blank space and you will see.

Comment: Good catch!  Updated to fix bug.  Applied the class to each radio input and label directly.